# Muiltiple Scroll Error in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a below html page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test Page </title>

    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="testdiv" style="height:300px; width:200px; overflow:scroll;">
                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div                This is a sample div

                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   </body>

</html>
```

I this page i added the below script

```
<script>
$( window ).scroll(function(){
    alert('Window Scroll');
});

$('#testdiv').scroll(function(){
    alert('testdiv Scroll');
});

</script>
```

Which will alert me which scroll action is called.

if i scroll in body it alerts me as `Window Scroll`

if i scroll in a div which is inside of the body its alerting me as `testdiv scroll`,`Window Scroll`

but it should alert only `testdiv scroll` why its alerting me 2 scroll events

Comment: On my FF 30, i've not this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#testdiv').scroll(function(e){
    alert('testdiv Scroll');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your scroll event bubbles up. Please see [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) for the event bubbling explanation.